# How to deal with thread hanging in a Java ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I'm using `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREADS)` where `THREADS=20` for sending events asynchronously through a rest service.
A couple weeks ago I experienced some unexpected problems when the rest service I'm consuming went down or began to response slower.

**1.** First, the LinkedBlockingQueue managed by the thread pool, suffered a bottleneck since it could not finish processes faster than new processes were created. So eventually it reached the max capacity allowed `(Integer.MAX_VALUE)` and great part of the heap memory was in use by the queue.

**2.** Second, although the rest service recovered and began to response in time again, the thread pool seemed to be in a "hanging state" where no more events were sent. I had to restart the application to fix the problem and send events back.

Here's the output of the Memory Analyzer Tool with the heap dump at issue:

> One instance of "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor" loaded by
>   "" occupies 2,518,687,016 (94.69%) bytes. The
>   instance is referenced by
>   com.despegar.flights.keeper.concurrent.trace.TraceAwareExecutorServiceImpl
>   @ 0x695cf3550 , loaded by "sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @
>   0x694cfd810".
>
> Keywords java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0x694cfd810

And the static state of the ThreadPoolExecutor:

```
Type   |Name          |Value
----------------------------------
int    |TERMINATED    |1610612736
int    |TIDYING       |1073741824
int    |STOP          |536870912
int    |SHUTDOWN      |0
int    |RUNNING       |-536870912
int    |CAPACITY      |536870911
int    |COUNT_BITS    |29
----------------------------------
```

Here's the code:

```
public AsyncDispatchManager() {
    this.executorService = new TraceAwareExecutorServiceImpl(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREADS));
}

public void execute(String name, Runnable runnable) {
    this.executorService.submit(this.adaptRunnable(name, runnable));
}
```

Regarding to the queue, I don't want to spend more resources in it, so I would implement a limited queue and a rejection policy for this situations since I don't care to loss some events.

Do you think there's a more appropriate solution?

With the hanging threads I'm stuck. I don't understand the background problem and how to resolve it.

Did someone have to deal with such problems?

I'd really appreciate any proposed solution or information.

Comment: It seems like you should first understand why tasks aren't completing, and decide what you want to do about that. These other workarounds are just treating the symptoms of that underlying problem. Rejecting new tasks because all of your threads are hung might stop an out-of-memory condition, but you still aren't doing useful work. Timeout behavior and cancellation of a REST call depend heavily on the REST client you are using.